# CentOS 7 to Windows, can list smb shares but cannot mount

Tags: linux, mount, samba, centos-7

I have been asked to check the mount a windows share on a CentOs7 box, before it was working and now not working anymore (no clue from the customer on what could be changed)

Local mount point /backup
Windows share //xx.xx.xx.xx/000_BCK

I can ping the Windows machine with no problem

The local mount point exists

```
ls /backup
Prod  Test
```

I can see the share via smbclient, even if there is an error at the end

```
smbclient -L xx.xx.xx.xx -U backup -m SMB2
Enter SAMBA\backup's password:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        000_BCK         Disk
        ADMIN$          Disk      Amministrazione remota
        B$              Disk      Condivisione predefinita
        C$              Disk      Condivisione predefinita
        IPC$            IPC       IPC remoto
        VBRCatalog      Disk
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.
do_connect: Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx failed (Error NT_STATUS_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND)
Unable to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available
```

Running the same command with the -d3 switch

```
 smbclient -L xx.xx.0.39 -U backup -m SMB3 -d3
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[global]"
added interface ens160 ip=xx.xx.xx.xx bcast=xx.xx.3.255 netmask=255.255.252.0
added interface docker0 ip=xx.xy.0.1 bcast=xx.xy.255.255 netmask=255.255.0.0
added interface docker_gwbridge ip=xx.xz.0.1 bcast=xx.xz.255.255 netmask=255.255.0.0
Client started (version 4.10.16).
Connecting to xx.xx.0.39 at port 445
Enter SAMBA\backup's password:
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_negotiate' registered
Cannot do GSE to an IP address
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62898215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        000_BCK         Disk
        ADMIN$          Disk      Amministrazione remota
        B$              Disk      Condivisione predefinita
        C$              Disk      Condivisione predefinita
        I$              Disk      Condivisione predefinita
        IPC$            IPC       IPC remoto
        VBRCatalog      Disk
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.
Connecting to xx.xx.0.39 at port 139
Connecting to xx.xx.0.39 at port 139
do_connect: Connection to xx.xx.0.39 failed (Error NT_STATUS_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND)
Unable to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available
```

fstab is configured as follows

```
cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Thu Jul 26 12:32:02 2018
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
//xx.xx.xx.xx/000_BCK          /backup   cifs    uid=1000,credentials=/var/.smb39,iocharset=utf8,noperm,vers=1.0 0 0
```

I verified the credential file and it contains the correct credentials (those I used with smbclient)

if I run sudo mount -a I get "Host is down" as message

```
sudo mount -a
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Commenting that line in fstab, mount -a works fine so that's the "offending" line

After some more search, I tried to use smb 2 and now the error is different

I changed fstab to

```
//xx.xx.xx.xx/000_BCK          /backup   cifs    uid=1000,credentials=/var/.smb39,iocharset=utf8,noperm,vers=2.0 0 0
```

And now the error is

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

and in dmsg I see

```
[2227599.842439] Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[2227599.842455] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[2227599.842993] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

...but (beginning of the post) with smbclient those credentials seems working fine

this is the content of /var/.smb39

```
user=backup
password=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

I tried changing user to username but the result seems the same

There is no domain/workgroup specified in the credential file.
Could it be the problem?

Is there anything I should ask the customer to check on windows side?

Edit: I tried the following

1. the rights on the folders seem ok

   ls -l /backup
   totale 8
   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 20 apr 21.30 Prod
   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 20 apr 21.45 Test
2. Someone suggested me to check selinux permissions. Selinux looks disabled on the machine, so it should not interfere with my work

   getenforce
   Disabled

   cat /etc/selinux/config

   SELINUX=disabled
   SELINUXTYPE=minimum

Thanks for any hint to shed some light on this subject

VindalooMan

Answer (score 0):

After more googling (and after the customer told us a CentOs update had been recently done) we found the problem

https://shocksolution.com/2019/10/23/mount-cifs-error-13-after-update-centos-redhat-linux-7-6/

Relevant information from link:

> When authenticating as a local user, you now have to specify the host as the domain.

The solution is to add the domain to the credential file and switch to cifs 2.1

I post it in case anyone else should have the same problem

VindalooMan

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).